# Spring AOT Graalvm Native image with Spring Data Ldap Repository

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data, graalvm, aot

I'm trying to convert my springBoot API from JIT compilation to AOT compilation with GraalVM.

To do this, I'm building a docker image with buildtools :

gradle plugin :

```
    id("org.graalvm.buildtools.native") version "0.9.27"
```

build command : `gradle bootBuildImage`

run cmd : `docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 myproject:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`

error during API startup :

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.myproject.managers.UserManager required a bean of type 'com.myproject.domain.repository.user.UserRepository' that could not be found.
```

It seems that the UserRepository Bean Definition doesn't exist, GraalVM can't find the UserRepository Bean.

This is my UserRepository and My UserManager (kotlin) :

```kotlin
@Repository
interface UserRepository: LdapRepository<User> {
    fun findByUserId(uuid: String): Optional<User>
    fun findByMobile(mobile: String): Optional<User>
    fun findByMail(mail: String): Optional<User>
}
```

```kotlin
@Component
class UserManager(
    private val userRepository: UserRepository
) {
...
}
```

Do you know how I can make my Ldap Spring Data Repository compatible with AOT ?

---

**PS**
this is a part of my `build.gradle.kts` (I can change the versions if necessary) :

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.1.0"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.0"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.21"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.8.21"
    kotlin("plugin.noarg") version "1.8.21"
    kotlin("kapt") version "1.8.22"
    id("org.graalvm.buildtools.native") version "0.9.27"
}

val springVersion = "3.1.4"
val ktlVersion = "1.8.21"
val springLdapVersion = "3.1.4"

dependencies {
    // kotlin
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib", ktlVersion))
    implementation(kotlin("reflect", ktlVersion))
    testImplementation(kotlin("test", ktlVersion))
    // spring
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$springVersion")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:$springVersion")
    // ldap
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-ldap:$springLdapVersion")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}
```